# How to handle timeout periods in Rebol 3 schemes

Tags: networking, rebol, rebol3

A common way to initiate the async IO event system in Rebol 3 is to wait on the port. To check for a timeout, a value from the scheme is added to the wait block.

```
wait [port timeout]
```

But a default timeout for a small email message may not be appropriate for a multimegabyte file.

What's the best way of handling this?  If you're still receiving data, can you update the wait list while your script is receiving data so that you don't unnecessarily timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a port timeout should trigger based on packet timing, not the full request. So, setting a timeout of 30 seconds on email means you've not received a packet in 30 seconds.

Since packets tend to be small, they arrive quickly, and not to receive one for a long period would be indication of a networking/server failure, where you'd want to get the timeout. (The exception is when packet aggregation is happening, but still, there won't be so much aggregation that a long delay would normally occur.)

All that, said, I'm not sure they're implemented in R3. Based on the prior comment, I guess not. The networking system was one of the first parts I wrote for R3, and it was lean and mean, but certainly could use some attention.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that this has yet to be implemented.  In this post http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Ports_and_Schemes:_Issues issue 9: timeouts, Carl says

> The lower-level ports implemented by the device model already include
>   a timeout feature. It is not currently enabled, but it needs to be.
>   This would satisfy the first requirement for actions like CONNECT or
>   READ and their related timeouts. This method does not use a general
>   timer port, because lower-level port devices would have a problem with
>   making a higher level call to a port like that.
>
> At the higher levels, we have always planned to provide a TIMER scheme
>   for such ports. It should be possible to make that available fairly
>   soon, because the fundamental timing code and kernel-level wakeup
>   mechanism is already implemented (for the Win32 system API).

Answer (score 0):

how about a loop?
forever [ wait [port 1] if magic-port-has-data? port [process] ]

Comment: I think the tcp:// scheme should handle this ... somehow. I note the http scheme also has the same issue .. try downloading a large file and see it error with a timeout.

Comment: Tried. Based on rebol.net/wiki/Port_Examples#Read_all_of_large_file, look for ";!!"

https://gist.github.com/4686849

Comment: Sure, you've setup your own async handler, but the default 'read in the http scheme will timeout.  So, what I'm asking is, if there is a proposal to handle this automatically rather than asking the user to setup their own handlers.

Comment: I am confused. The default 'read does its own wait. Since you do your own wait, i thought you do it the async way. How can i use 'read and still do my own wait?
That 'read timeouts is a bug IMHO, it should timeout because of lag, not when the connection runs fine.

Comment: The default 'read in the http scheme checks to see if there is a default handler installed.  If so, it uses it to give the impression of a synchronous action, and there's a wait in there to kick things off.  If you use your own handler, and don't send the request on connect as in your example, then you can start things with a wait in  your read.